# GDB expressions

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
   0x00000000004013fb <+334>:   mov    0x602500(,%rax,8),%rdx
```

I want to know what `0x602500(,%rax,8)` means.

There are source code like this

```
 0x00000000004012fb <+78>:  movq   $0x400a8c,0x2011fa(%rip)        # 0x602500 <func>
   0x0000000000401306 <+89>:    movq   $0x400d44,0x2011f7(%rip)        # 0x602508 <func+8>
   0x0000000000401311 <+100>:   movq   $0x400faa,0x2011f4(%rip)        # 0x602510 <func+16>
   0x000000000040131c <+111>:   movq   $0x401262,0x2011f1(%rip)        # 0x602518 <func+24>
   0x0000000000401327 <+122>:   movq   $0x401295,0x2011ee(%rip)        # 0x602520 <func+32>
```

each 0x400a8c, 400d44, 400faa, 401262 and 401295 is address of functions
I guess `0x602500(,%rax,8)` choose proper function to execute by rax. But I want to make sure about my guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Gnu documentation:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory

```
An Intel syntax indirect memory reference of the form

     section:[base + index*scale + disp]

is translated into the AT&T syntax

     section:disp(base, index, scale)
```

In other words:

1. You derive a pointer (compute an address) from rax, scale = 8
2. Then you take the offset of 0x602500 from that address
3. And write that value (the value at address + 0x602500) to %rdx

Scale values might be 1, 2, 4, or 8: byte, 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit.